# Discord.py async function missing positional argument it already has

Tags: python, discord, pycharm, discord.py

(all of my code is from a tutorial i followed)

im a beginner to discord.py. i am trying to make the bot get my username and have a different response based on the username. in another python script for the same project, i can see that message.author is what gets the username

```
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        # Make sure bot doesn't get stuck in an infinite loop
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        # Get data about the user
        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)
```

so i tried to put that in the script that generates the responses as shown below

```
def handle_response(message) -> str:
    p_message = message.lower()
    if p_message == 'hello':
        if message.author=="Desper"
           return 'hey desper'
        return 'Hey there!'
```

when i say "hello" it will give me this error here

```
handle_response() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user_message'
```

[here are the scripts if they are needed](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kaa8zFb8XXFlJIhBuukLqnWSvkgdL98c?usp=share_link). i removed my token and replaced it with

```
PUT TOKEN HERE ---------------------
```

Comment: Don't post code or error messages as images.  Images are hard to work with.  Please edit your question and post all code and errors as plain text.

Comment: @JohnGordon sorry about that. fixed

Answer (score 0):

In your bot.py file, you have this line in your send_message function:

```
response = responses.handle_response(user_message)
```

Here you pass 1 argument, not the 2 that you defined in your function signature.

Comment: that fixes that issue but causes another one. i now get the error 'Message' object has no attribute 'lower'    it pertains to p_message = message.lower() in responses.py

Comment: can you post your call to `handle_response()`? Also, `.lower()` works on `str` types. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=lower#str.lower

Comment: i'll be honest i dont know what any of that means. could you explain in simpler terms?

Comment: The error message `'Message' object has no attribute 'lower'` means that you are trying to treat an object of type `Message` as a string. Convert the `Message` to a string, then you can call `.lower()` on the string.